# How to increment dates in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql, virtuoso

How can I increment numbers in general and dates in particular in SPARQL? Concretely, I have a filter to get me only people born today: 
`FILTER (STRLEN(STR(?born)) > 6 && (SUBSTR(STR(?born),6)=SUBSTR(STR(bif:curdate('')),6))`. 
How to extend this filter so I get also people born in next two days?

(I may accept/ignore or correct the use the private function)

**UPDATE**

As the proposed solution didn't work on DBpedia, I implemented it with Virtuoso private function but I have no idea, apart from using `UNION`, how to change the filter or find another elegant solution so that I get people born today, tomorrow and the day after tomorrow. Currently this part of the query looks like this:

```
BIND ((SUBSTR(STR(?born),6)=SUBSTR(STR(now()),6,5)) as ?tday)
BIND ((SUBSTR(STR(?born),6)=SUBSTR(STR(bif:dateadd("day", 1, now())),6,5)) as ?tday1)
BIND ((SUBSTR(STR(?born),6)=SUBSTR(STR(bif:dateadd("day", 2, now())),6,5)) as ?tday2)

FILTER (STRLEN(STR(?born)) > 6)
FILTER (?tday) .
```

Replacing `?tday` with `?tday1` and `?tday2'` works fine, but how all three dates in the result?

Comment: If your endpoint supports duration literals, you might just be able to add a two day duration to the date... are you using virtuoso?

Comment: Yes, Virtuoso. If I run it today, I want to get 04-17, -18, -19. But then, when I run it on 29th, I want, of course, 04-29, 04-30, and 05-01. I thought of using `op:numeric-add` in other cases, but with dates... no clue.

Comment: Dates and dateTimes can be xsd:duration.

Comment: look at the query in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36724188/why-filter-doesnt-work-in-this-context it could give you some clue

Comment: @William that's the same approach I used in my answer on this question, but it sounds like virtuoso doesn't do duration arithmetic.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I thought duration arithmetic is a standard sparql 1.1 operation

Comment: I thought it was too, but I don't think it is, actually.  Some functions on date times are standard, but I don't think that all the comparisons and arithmetic are.

Comment: I guess I have to try it bifs then. There are plenty of those for manipulating temporal data.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor so I implemented it with `bif:dateadd` but I don't know how to get all the dates by FILTER or some other way, avoiding `UNION` - see updated question.

Comment: This looks like it may be a Virtuoso-specific issue... so likely better raised on the [Virtuoso Users mailing list](https://lists.sourceforge.net/lists/listinfo/virtuoso-users/), the [OpenLink Support Forums](http://boards.openlinksw.com/support/index.php), or an [OpenLink Support Case](http://support.openlinksw.com/support/online-support.vsp).  (ObDisclaimer: I work for OpenLink Software, producer of Virtuoso.)

Comment: @TallTed Thanks for the suggestion, but Re:Vrtuoso, I'll first use the support contract we have and then turn to forums. In any case, currently I'm quite happy to use `bif:dateadd` instead of `xsd:duration`. But for your information, all three tests with `xsd:duration` - dbpedia, internal VOS and universal server - failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some attempts, I found the solution that works fine for me. Here I'm taking all born today and in the next 7 days:

```
values ?d {0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7}

BIND ((SUBSTR(STR(?born),6) as ?bornSTR))
BIND ((SUBSTR(STR(bif:dateadd("day", ?d, now())),6,5)) as ?day)

FILTER (STRLEN(STR(?born)) > 6 &&  STR(?bornSTR) = STR(?day))
```

Answer (score 3):

If your endpoint supports duration arithmetic, you can add a duration to the date.  For instance, here we can add a duration of two days to a date and see the correct behavior where the end date wraps around to the next month:

```sql
prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

select ?begin ?end where {
  values ?begin { "2005-02-28T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime }
  values ?duration { "P2DT0H0M0.000S"^^xsd:duration }
  bind( (?begin + ?duration) as ?end)
}
```

```
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| begin                                | end                                      |
===================================================================================
| "2005-02-28T00:00:00Z"^^xsd:dateTime | "2005-03-02T00:00:00.000Z"^^xsd:dateTime |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: I'm using DBpedia and there it doesn't work with `xsd:duration`.