# Why filter doesn't work in this context?

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web, owl, ontology

This is the query and the result:

[image]

As you see, I am filtering out the users that are `bo:ania`, so why do they still appear?

However, if I remove the widecard and select just the users `?user`, `bo:ania` doesn't appear

[image]

I didn't provide a minimum data example because this is a question about how filter and wildcard work, not about a problem in extracting some data from a data set. However, if you need a minimum data, I'm more than happy to provide it.

Comment: off-topic: I think you mean wildcard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`?specificUser` is bound to `bo:ania` by your `VALUES` statement.  `?user` is an entirely different binding defined by the other triple patterns.  Your `FILTER` says to filter out results where `?user = bo:ania`, and it appears to be doing that correctly, seeing that `?user` is not bound to `bo:ania` in any of the results.

BTW, there isn't a need to use `VALUES` in this case unless you want to inspect multiple values.  If it's just the one value, then the following would work, and not have you wondering why the binding to `bo:ania` is included in the result set:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
  ?user a rs:user .
  ?user rs:hasRated ?rating .
  ?rating rs:hasRatingDate ?ratngDate .
  FILTER (?ratingDates >= (now() -"P10000F"^^xsd:duration) )
  FILTER (?user != bo:ania)
}
```

Comment: Even if there's only one value to use, **values** Can reduce one source of typos by letting the IRI appear just once,  and can make the projection easier, since the value is bound to a variable.

Comment: I don't see any of that in the above query(?)  In the general case I don't see a difference between `VALUES` with one binding and `BIND`, other than user preference.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor yes values save me tones of typos, i use it always, you tought me that, thanks a lot